# How to reconcile a dynamic KO mapping with manual?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

I frequently have a situation where I want to have a C# ViewModel mapped to a knockout viewModel in a view.

This means I'll usually do something like:

```
<script>
    var viewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model));
</script>
```

And this gets the C# ViewModel into my viewModel just fine.  But I often want to allow the user to interact with the viewModel in meaningful ways, so say my model is a `List<User>` and `User` has properties `Name` and `Age`.  My view might look like:

```
<table class="table">
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: viewModel">
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" data-bind="value: Name" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" data-bind="value: Age" /></td>
            <td><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" data-bind="click: Remove"></span></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<button type="button" data-bind="click: AddUser">Add User</button>
```

Now I've got a button to remove each `User` in each row, but in order to give that functionality, I'll need to add a `Remove` method to each `User` in the `List`.  This is where my uncertainty begins.  What I have been doing is basically:

```
<script>
    var vm = ko.mapping.fromJS(@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model));

    var viewModel = function (vm) {
        var self = {};

        self.Users = vm;

        ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.Users(), function(item) {
            item.Remove = function() 
            {
                self.Users.remove(this);
            }
        });

        self.AddUser = function() {
            self.Users.push({
               Name: "",
               Age: ""
            });
        }
    }

</script>
```

Although this works (I freehanded this, so there may be some errors), it seems overly verbose and clunky to have to iterate through my mapped viewmodel to add needed functions and so on.   Is there a cleaner way to do this, or am I just being finicky?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would go another way with this one and put the remove() function in your viewmodel:

```
var viewModel = function (vm) {
    var self = {};

    self.Users = vm;

    self.remove = function(item) {
        self.Users.remove(item);
    };

    self.AddUser = function() {
        self.Users.push({
           Name: "",
           Age: ""
        });
    }
}
```

and then call it in your view like this:

```
<td><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" data-bind="click: $parent.remove"></span></td>
```